# How can I get a method reference for an instance method with a dynamically bound target

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda, delegates

In C# we can instantiate a Delegate through a method reference to static method or an instance method. Example:

```
Func<object, object, bool> refEquals = Object.ReferenceEquals;  // target = null
Func<string> toStr = new Object().ToString; // target = new Object()
```

For the latter the Delegate’s target is the `new Object()`, whereas the former has a `null` target.

But, how can I instantiate a Delegate for the `ToString` method reference without a pre-defined `target`? In this case, I would like that the `ToString`’s target would be bound to the Delegate’s argument. This could be useful, for instance, to call a certain instance method to all items of an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
Func<object, string> toStr = Object.ToString; // the target (this) would be the Func’s argument
IEnumerable<T> dataSrc = ...
IEnumerable<String> dataSrc = dataSrc.Select(toStr);
```

However, first line does not compile:

> error CS0123: No overload for 'ToString' matches delegate 'System.Func'

Java 8 provides this feature through [Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#type). How can I achieve this same feature in .Net?

---

I know that we could surpass this limitation with a lambda expression, such as:

```
 Func<Object, String> toStr = item => item.ToString();
```

However, this incurs in a further indirection to call the `ToString` instance method and for that reason I am not considering this workaround as a valid solution for my question.

Comment: I don't know java, but in `C#` you have to pass instance of object to delegate if you need it. Never heard of *arbitrary object* or anything like this. With reflection (using `StackFrame`) you can get method name, etc., but not much and that would be lambda (which you are trying to avoid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via *Reflection*, you can get an equivalent behavior to that one described in Java 8. You can create an instance of a Delegate with a `null` target and dynamically binding its first argument to the `this` method parameter. For your example you can create the `toStr` delegate in the following way:

```
MethodInfo methodToStr = typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString");
Func<Object, String> toStr = (Func<Object, String>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(
            typeof(Func<Object, String>),
            methodToStr);
```

Comment: I think the real answer is, "In c#, without lambda or helper method, you can not". This is as close as it gets though - but risk of `AmbiguousMatchException` for the general case.

Comment: @Tewr you may get that exception on Delegate instantiation.